# How to cut and paste files in c++

Tags: c++, string, rename

I am trying to use rename function to change files locations in c++. My problem is that I want to have as input and output strings and rename it seems to work only with chars. What have to do??

EDIT1:

```
 for(int i=0; i<dirs.size(); i++){
    if(directories.size()>1)
       for (int k=0; k<= directories.size()/2; k++){
         result = rename((filePath+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str(), ("test1/"+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str());
       } 
    }
  }
```

Basically I want to cut and paste the half files of filePath/dir[i] dir to newfilePath/dir[i] dir. newFilePath directory is empty so I want also to create the same dir[i] folders and cut the files into the new path. It seems that rename doesn't create new folders.

EDIT2:

I add mkdir function in order to create the same dir[i] folders in the new directory. However, the rename function doesn't move files in the new directories!!

```
for(int i=0; i<dirs.size();i++){
        if(directories.size()>1){
          mkdir(dirs[i].c_str(), 0777);
            for (int k=0; k<= directories.size()/2; k++){
                 result= rename( (filePath+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str() , ("test1/"+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str()  );
             }
         }
 }
```

Comment: use the `str()` member function of `std::string` to convert to `const char*` in the arguments.

Comment: @arne It should be `c_str()`.

Comment: Ok basically i ve got a logical error here. "test1" folder is empty and I want to create inside test1 folder the same dirs folders with half of directories files (from filePath folder). It seems that with rename function I cant create new folders. Any idea here?

Comment: @timrau you're right.

Comment: c_str() works fine but I think rename is not what i need in the end! I want to cut and paste some of directories files in other folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `c_str` method of `std::string`:

```
for (int k=0; k<= directories.size()/2; k++){
  result = rename((filePath+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str(), ("test1/"+dirs[i]+directories[k]).c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `c_str` function to access string as a C null-terminated array:

```
for( int k=0; k<= directories.size()/2; k++ ){
    std::string oldstr = filePath+dirs[i]+directories[k];
    std::string newstr = "test1/"+dirs[i]+directories[k]; 
    result = rename( oldstr.c_str() , newstr.c_str() );
}
```

or `data` function if you are using C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Ok silly me I forgot to add "/" in the path between filepath and dir[i], rename works fine!!